# 403 Forbidden response – what should I look for?

Tags: php, permissions, webserver

I have a script giving me error `403 Forbidden error`, it's just a copy of another script but the difference in this is that both use another mysql class to access database.

My whole project is complete and this is last file so I don't want to do the whole work again for a single file.

Server logs shows that **client denied by server configuration:**

What should I look for?

I have tried the following:

- Permissions are 644
- New file with just simple echo gives 403 too
- Changed name of folder

However, `index.php` works perfectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue occurs if you have had denied for all in your `.htaccess` file. Changing that resolves the issue.

Comment: Can you post the changes you made to you .htaccess file

Comment: Thanks this was this for me. Deleted the .htaccess and alright. Old installation had `<FilesMatch '.(php|php5|phtml)$'>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>`

Answer (score 16):

Check the permissions and also ***ownership*** of the file. Generally, 403 means that the web server doesn't have the rights to read the file and therefore can't continue the request. The permissions may be set correctly, however the file might be owned by another account on the server - an account that isn't part of the same group as the account which is running the server.

For instance, I believe* Apache is ran by default under the `httpd` user account, which is part of the `httpd` group. However, the FTP user you're logging in as (for instance `ftpuser`) might not be part of the `httpd` group. So, in copying the file you've created it under a different user account and Apache won't get execute access with `644`.

* it's been a while since I've used apache, but it's similar under nginx.

Comment: +1: This is the most common cause I've seen of 403 Forbidden errors.

Comment: i checked permissions its 644, i even placed a new file with just simple echo and even that was giving a 403 error, irenamed the folder too but no use, however the index.php file i running perfect

Comment: Please see changes to answer.

Comment: Usage of rsync utility is free from these problems.E.g. rsync -v -u -a -r --delete --rsh=ssh --stats ../source_folder/*  user@www.remote_address.net:/var/www/destination_folder/

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The `.htaccess` file in my root folder has this code:

```
<Files ~ "\.(php|php5|py|jsp|cgi|sh)$">
    Require all denied
</Files>
```

But there was a folder `/example` where I needed to call php files, so I created a `.htaccess` file in that specific folder with this content:

```
<Files ~ "\.(php)$">
    Require all granted
</Files>
```

**Note**: I am running Apache 2.4