# 403 Forbidden trying to execute php scripts

Tags: php, apache, permissions

Fresh install of a Debian server. Apache2, PHP5.

When I try to browse a PHP file I get 403 Forbidden. I am able to browse to html files.

I have tried the following:

- Reinstalled Apache, PHP, libapache2-mod-php5
- Restarted Apache
- Checked the conf file thoroughly, copied from default, set the correct Directory path  and allow from all
- Checked permissions of directory, as a test have given full 777 permission to /var/www/site - still forbidden

Cant think of what else to try ?

Comment: you have set 755 for the php file?

Comment: ive also tried chown the directory www-data:www-data

Comment: for the file not for the directory

Comment: apache user is www-data and it owns the directory

Comment: give 666 permission to /var/www/site and try

Comment: @shakti: 777 doesn't work already. why would u want to test using lower permission levels?

Comment: usually, i use 755 instead of 777 because if you forget to set anything back to 755, it can be dangerous for other users to alter your scripts or create new scripts

Comment: try disabling `mod_alias`. there might be a misconfiguration in the scripts directory

Comment: I tried a2dismod mod_alias, does not exist

Comment: permissions and owner of `/var/www`?

Comment: Have you checked access and error logs? I have often found relevant information in similar cases.

Comment: @Tim - Do you have the order ? like `Order allow,deny`

Comment: Yes, conf file has Order, allow, deny then allow from all.. as i said.. html files work fine

Comment: access log just shows whole bunch of 403's and error log just shows forbiddens, nothing not expected

Comment: I added +ExecCGI - It now gives me an internal server error as opposed to 403

Comment: hope not this case ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300125/php-script-403-forbidden-error

Comment: I'm having exactly this same issue.. and none of your responses helped me trying to fix it :\

Answer (score 2):

Perform `chmod 755` of the directory in which the PHP scripts reside.

After that restart the Apache/nginx server

or

if above method not work then contact your hosting provider to whitelist that url to phpscript because it can be issue with mod_security. Its the most annoying thing hostgator user are facing.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the alow/deny pattern in your http.conf is set correctly. 
What's written to the apache error log?

Comment: Wouldnt this sort of thing end up in the access log?