# Odd error using PHP header()

Tags: php, html, header

I'm getting the following error:

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/89/11421189/html/notfound.php:2) in /home/content/89/11421189/html/notfound.php on line 4

In my file 'notfound.php', which uses the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php//Line 2
ob_start();
header('Location:http://www.website.com/index.php?page=404.php', true, 302);
exit;
?>
<head>
</head>
<html>
</html>
```

Note that there is NO whitespace before the PHP tag, or AFTER it. No matter where I move it to (even if it's all on the same line), that line is the culprit in the error. What am I doing wrong here?

[EDIT] Note:
If I move the PHP to before the DOCTYPE tag, navigating to this file gives me an error 403: forbidden. The location is fine, since I can copy/paste it into the address bar without issues. Can you not pass GET arguments through header()?

Comment: remove the line - <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Comment: remove everything in the file except `<?php header('Location:http://www.website.com/index.php?page=404.php', true, 302);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't output headers after anything has been output. The DOCTYPE is output before the header().

Comment: Well, I tried moving the PHP before the doctype, but then when I load the page it says ERROR 403: Forbidden.

Comment: in that case maybe you need to change the mode of your file to 777 ie if your are using linux just execute this command - chmod 777 <your php file name>

Comment: I can copy/paste the location target URL into the address bar and it loads just fine.

Comment: @user2577320 - try replacing the URL with something that definitely works. Clearly, the original error is solved. Can you post the URL?

Comment: I just tried changing the target URL with http://www.google.com, and it still says forbidden. The test URL is side7entertainment.org

Comment: Hello @user2577320. It appears that markdwhite has solved the original issue. You should mark his solution as solved. If you are getting a 403 error now that will be b/c you either have the permissions wrong but most likely an incorrect url. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300125/php-script-403-forbidden-error