# 403 Forbidden Checkboxes PDO/PHP Syntax Issue PHPMYADMIN/WAMP

Tags: php, checkbox, pdo, syntax, phpmyadmin

Ok, so I was following this tutorial, which who knows, may or may not be accurate.
when I choose submit, I get a 403 error. and a screen with half the PHP code.

from where I am sitting it is a syntax error, but for the life of me, I cannot figure out why. I have run it through notepad++ phpdesigner and a few online checkers. most of them say it is fine, however the lint check shows an syntax error to begin with, beyond that I am stumped.

at first I thought the 403 error was permission based however I went back to another project and could add data to the PHPMYADMIN database, so that all checks out. I have posted the code below, so if someone wants to give it a glance and set me on the right path, that would be great.

for some reason I cannot get the mysqli to talk to my apache, so I am stuck with pdo options for projects. Havent figured out how to fix that issue as yet.

thanks

```
<?php
   $fruitArray = array('orange', 'apple', 'grapefruit', 'banana', 'watermelon');
   if(isset($_POST['btn_save']))
   {   try
       {  $dbcon = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db", 'root', 'password');
          $dbcon->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
       }  catch (PDOException $e) {echo $e->getMessage(); }

       if(isset( $_POST['fruit']))
       {  $values = array();
          foreach($_POST['fruit'] as $selection )
          {  if(in_array($selection, $fruitArray))
             {  $values[ $selection ] = 1; }
             else
             {  $values[ $selection ] = 0; }
          } // end of foreach.

          try // save user selection to the database
          {  $DBH = $dbcon->prepare("INSERT INTO table_fruit 
                      (orange, apple, grapefruit, banana, watermelon )
               VALUES (:DBorange, :DBapple, :DBgrapefruit, :DBbanana, :DBwatermelon)");
        $DBH->bindParam(':DBorange',     $values['orange']);
        $DBH->bindParam(':DBapple',      $values['apple']);
        $DBH->bindParam(':DBgrapefruit', $values['grapefruit']);
        $DBH->bindParam(':DBbanana',     $values['banana']);
        $DBH->bindParam(':DBwatermelon', $values['watermelon']);
        $DBH->execute();
           }  catch(PDOException $e) { echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage(); }
      }
      else
      {  echo 'No checkbox selection made...'; }
   } // End of, if statement from the button check

?>

<span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 12px;">
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Checkbox selection using PHP (using PDO) and MySQL v2</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h2>Pick your most favourite fruits:</h2>
      <form name="fruitcheckbox" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
         <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="orange"> Orange
         <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="apple"> Apple
         <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="grapefruit"> Grapefruit
         <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="banana"> Banana
         <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="watermelon"> Watermelon
         <br>
         <input type="submit" value="Save" name="btn_save">
      </form>
   </body>
</html> </span>
```

AFTER HTML is EXECUTED. whether in IE, EDGE or CHROME.

setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ); } catch (PDOException $e) {echo $e->getMessage(); } if(isset( $_POST['fruit'])) { $values = array(); foreach($_POST['fruit'] as $selection ) { if(in_array($selection, $fruitArray)) { $values[ $selection ] = 1; } else { $values[ $selection ] = 0; } } // end of foreach. try // save user selection to the database { $DBH = $dbcon->prepare("INSERT INTO table_fruit (orange, apple, grapefruit, banana, watermelon ) VALUES (:DBorange, :DBapple, :DBgrapefruit, :DBbanana, :DBwatermelon)"); $DBH->bindParam(':DBorange', $values['orange']); $DBH->bindParam(':DBapple', $values['apple']); $DBH->bindParam(':DBgrapefruit', $values['grapefruit']); $DBH->bindParam(':DBbanana', $values['banana']); $DBH->bindParam(':DBwatermelon', $values['watermelon']); $DBH->execute(); } catch(PDOException $e) { echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage(); } } else { echo 'No checkbox selection made...'; } } // End of, if statement from the button check ?> 
Pick your most favourite fruits:

Orange  Apple  Grapefruit  Banana  Watermelon

and when I make a selection I get

http://localhost/my-site/insertintodbpdo/%3C?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>
u don't have permission to access /my-site/insertintodbpdo/< on this server.

Comment: You're better off checking your server's error logs instead of basic syntax checkers. The error could really be anything, such as a mis-configured web server to file permissions, etc.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300125/php-script-403-forbidden-error

Comment: much appreciated. ill check when I get home later. basically when I run the index.html I get ABOVE

Comment: fixed. its a php file. the way the tutorial was worded, I assumed it was html.